# Unable to start an imported image file

Tags: docker

I am new to docker and i am using `docker-ce-19.03.4-3.el7.x86_64` on centos7.

*On my machine A:*

- I started a new container:

```
docker run -d -p 12345:12345 oddrationale/docker-shadowsocks -s 0.0.0.0 -p 12345 -k welcome -m aes-256-cfb`
```

- And I used docker export to export this container:

  `docker export -o oddss.tar ae6f`

Then I import the container on a machine B using

`docker import oddss.tar oddss:v1`

Then i try to start the container:

```
docker run -d -p 12345:12345 oddss:v1 -s 0.0.0.0 -p 12345 -k welcome -m aes-256-cfb。
```

I got the below error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"-s\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

What went wrong?

By the way:
On my machineA i `docker inspect xxxx`(inpsect original image):

```
[root@localhost ~]# docker inspect 4cbc
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:4cbc49994adea9b85e178fc2c2e5b42e778ac56093e63837a202c15f781940d0",
        "RepoTags": [
            "oddrationale/docker-shadowsocks:latest"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [
            "oddrationale/docker-shadowsocks@sha256:e3ce4f13cef8ef77ed09972c61c6e4f9329ec3c5b80e823649799d39b9dbdad2"
        ],
        "Parent": "",
        "Comment": "",
        "Created": "2017-09-17T21:37:08.505316506Z",
        "Container": "287b24b1654f396305565ad6f1e9f708309d6454c1002052f61aae9b693c6a3b",
        "ContainerConfig": {
            "Hostname": "287b24b1654f",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "#(nop) ",
                "ENTRYPOINT [\"/usr/local/bin/ssserver\"]"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "sha256:7894fa03a4cfec768ffc5d9f9383c94367907c672a05989e84c23883ca24c18e",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/usr/local/bin/ssserver"
            ],
            "OnBuild": [],
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "DockerVersion": "17.06.1-ce",
        "Author": "Dariel Dato-on <oddrationale@gmail.com>",
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
            ],
            "Cmd": null,
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "sha256:7894fa03a4cfec768ffc5d9f9383c94367907c672a05989e84c23883ca24c18e",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/usr/local/bin/ssserver"
            ],
            "OnBuild": [],
            "Labels": null
        },
        "Architecture": "amd64",
        "Os": "linux",
        "Size": 426506496,
        "VirtualSize": 426506496,
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/cc2f3742d67c88aaabdc32f7428d31d9b4bd83e92eb3eb445d6524ea17b7c109/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/197bc874ea1de563b1d932842baceb6dbb9ec594b39621ffcf26f052b51b1b7c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f46b355758209160d015cc7bfbfca7b97658f047b11e9f5f36ae115861dfdfaf/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f5147a34f60f7b8b0297e9b03f3e5e547ec56181c74f3de11a6d277a9463d2df/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/45d0254499457a4d0945ea695d93b0e0d43efad4c7ffc392172099ec43ecffde/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f94c1723e6c26bab9f89f91f90050a146dc77e482a03109549d5acf0da769595/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6daa9b4a13892f16e267e1154a5d53619f2c83559ae82b05fb0806c5e3d171dd/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6daa9b4a13892f16e267e1154a5d53619f2c83559ae82b05fb0806c5e3d171dd/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6daa9b4a13892f16e267e1154a5d53619f2c83559ae82b05fb0806c5e3d171dd/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "RootFS": {
            "Type": "layers",
            "Layers": [
                "sha256:8aa4fcad5eeb286fe9696898d988dc85503c6392d1a2bd9023911fb0d6d27081",
                "sha256:ebf3d6975c708f538b14a5267afd2c4c64e8243d195aa11d878e566a7e64c727",
                "sha256:a76db6d8fac422acd5fb6c28166c906c202639e4e833cf88c7d4965b806c5437",
                "sha256:cd1d6655b4e44bb95df75bd2ecde4ad6799dd23337a9dedadf6e0b7f0efdc27e",
                "sha256:3996d0debc49f9a96c25d4ab7a5c9e824229c09976551b80ab0da70fa993a10d",
                "sha256:2315a4c2653559a1c92015435eee90a662342572996a1cb170e4965f8cd3e93c",
                "sha256:2cad94c7b276af8892ed48f29840f404b55ef8effac54cb32897ae54e74a8360"
            ]
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "LastTagTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        }
    }
]
```

On my machineB i `docker inspect xxxx`(inpsect this imported image):

```
[root@localhost ~]# docker inspect 7f8b5fefe798
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:7f8b5fefe7982ce61736a49312f10a8dfc93737d3491d14c6426127b2a08821e",
        "RepoTags": [
            "oddss:v1"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [],
        "Parent": "",
        "Comment": "Imported from -",
        "Created": "2019-12-10T02:43:46.092238586Z",
        "Container": "",
        "ContainerConfig": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": null,
            "Cmd": null,
            "Image": "",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": null
        },
        "DockerVersion": "19.03.4",
        "Author": "",
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": null,
            "Cmd": null,
            "Image": "",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": null
        },
        "Architecture": "amd64",
        "Os": "linux",
        "Size": 391540765,
        "VirtualSize": 391540765,
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d51e9744d68cb75c743da4eaf3da6abf865ad58402eb084300eac4cb471bcd21/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d51e9744d68cb75c743da4eaf3da6abf865ad58402eb084300eac4cb471bcd21/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d51e9744d68cb75c743da4eaf3da6abf865ad58402eb084300eac4cb471bcd21/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "RootFS": {
            "Type": "layers",
            "Layers": [
                "sha256:796a1d0347f88a0521686f0329c3d3451b4852a29092f21a110b0997d2f1d34d"
            ]
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "LastTagTime": "2019-12-09T18:43:46.095089283-08:00"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: try using `docker save` and `docker load`.

Comment: also use `docker run -d -p 12345:12345  -s 0.0.0.0 -p 12345 -k welcome -m aes-256-cfb oddss:v1`. AFAIK, image name should be at the end.

Comment: 1.I have to use export/import :(  2.Commands should be placed after the image name

Comment: When you want to run an imported image container, Notice the workdir,entrypoint,env of the original image. And you need to `docker run` new container with these params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem you're having is that `export` does not REALLY capture a container (it just makes a tarball of the filesystem)- note that your new image has no entrypoint or command. That's what that error means- your container has no `entrypoint` specified, so it is interpreting `-s 0.0.0.0 -p 12345 -k welcome -m aes-256-cfb。` as the entrypoint (and -s is not a valid command).

But... don't do this. Not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but its fighting the way the stuff works. If you need to modify a container, use a Dockerfile, build an image.

EDIT

To elaborate a bit- exporting a container (what you're doing) is a bad idea. Images, however are meant to be used this way. `docker image save` and `docker image import` are probably what you want- turn an image into a tarball, and then back into an image, with all the image metadata that was set up in the dockerfile preserved.

If you REALLY need to run a container and then move it, you can do `docker commit` to create a new image from a running container, followed by the `save/import` mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks! This is an odd requirement, but I had to do it this way: I needed to receive an image file over a TCP connection and import it on my own machine. So. is there a way to specify entrypoint when `docker run` to run this container?

Comment: I added a bit more- could you elaborate a bit though? I feel like there is probably an easier way to accomplish whatever you are trying to do :)

Comment: Thanks again!  I need to interact with another platform, which will send me the exported container through a TCP channel, and I need to import this file into my own machine.So I had to use docker import instead of docker load.

Comment: I try to use : `docker run -d -p 12345:12345 oddss:v1  /usr/local/bin/ssserver  -s 0.0.0.0 -p 12345 -k welcome -m aes-256-cfb` ,and it works.

Comment: If the only thing you were missing was the command (no environment variables or USER directives or anything), then that is true, it will work :)

Comment: It doesn't really seem like a good way to go.Although it works, as you said, there are other things missing such as environment variables.

Comment: Yes, you should export an image, not a container. Even if you can't use a registry for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm sorry I can't √ that answer. I will △ this answer when i got 15  reputation..